# Laravel 5 Form request validation with parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using **form request** validation and there are some rules that needs external values as a parameters.

Here are my validation rules for editing a business profile inside a form request class,

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|unique:businesses,name,'.$business->id,
        'url' => 'required|url|unique:businesses'
    ];
}
```

I can use this on the controller by type hinting it.

```
public function postBusinessEdit(BusinessEditRequest $request, Business $business)
{
    //
}
```

But how to pass the `$business` object as a **parameter** to the `rules` method?

Comment: import the model(i assume $business is a model) into your request class & get the object manually

Comment: @NehalHasnayeen yes the business is a model but it is type hinted on to the controller method that uses route model bindings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lets say this is your model binding:

```
$router->model('business', 'App\Business');
```

Then you can reference the `Business` class from within the `FormRequest` object like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    $business = $this->route()->getParameter('business');
    // rest of the code
}
```

Note that if you use your form request both for create and update validation, while creating the record, the business variable will be `null` because your object does not exists yet. So take care to make the needed checks before referencing the object properties or methods.

Comment: you can do shorter `$this->route('business')`

Answer (score 9):

There can be many ways to achieve this. I do it as below.

You can have a hidden field 'id' in your business form like bellow,

```
{!! Form::hidden('id', $business->id) !!}
```

and you can retrieve this `id` in `FormRequest` as below,

```
public function rules()
{
    $businessId = $this->input('id');

    return [
        'name' => 'required|unique:businesses,name,'.$businessId,
        'url' => 'required|url|unique:businesses'
    ];
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is simpler than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

For those who switched to laravel 5 :

```
public function rules()
{
    $business = $this->route('business');
    // rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let say if we have a scenario like we want to change our validation rules depends on the `type` that we pass in with the route. For example:

```
app.dev/business/{type}
```

For different type of business, we have different validation rules. All we need to do is type-hint the request on your controller method.

```
public function store(StoreBusiness $request)
{
    // The incoming request is valid...
}
```

For the custom form request

```
class StoreBussiness extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules()
    {
        $type = $this->route()->parameter('type');

        $rules = [];
        if ($type === 'a') {
        }

        return rules;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.5 at least (haven't checked older versions), once you did your explicit binding (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding), you can get your model directly through $this:

```
class StoreBussiness extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [];
        if ($this->type === 'a') {
        }

        return rules;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Laravel 5.6 you may type hint it in the rules method:

```
public function rules(Business $business)
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|unique:businesses,name,'.$business->id,
        'url' => 'required|url|unique:businesses'
    ];
}
```

See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation) for more:

> You may type-hint any dependencies you need within the rules method's signature. They will automatically be resolved via the Laravel service container.

Comment: Adam ... for example, if you have `public function update(BusinessUpdateRequest $request, Business $business) {...}` on the BusinessController.php, how do you pass the `$business` to the BusinessUpdateRequest.php so you can uses this parameter on the "rules" method like you do on your example???

Comment: @zacktagnan you need to bind $business to the server container. It will be resolved automatically :)

Comment: Adam ... Sorry, but I don't know how to "bind $business to the server container" Could you do an example of that?

Comment: @zacktagnan create a service provider and bind your class. Read https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/container and https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/providers#the-register-method to get started